# Match pattern only starting or ending with with non-alpha numeric or space

Tags: regex

Trying this now for a while and I have lost my knowledge...

How can I match any string pattern "OOC"? Starting or ending with a space or non-alphanumerical charachter?

```
no match | asdOOCasd
no match | asdasdOOC
no match | OOCasdasd
match    | asd OOC asd
match    | asd-OOC-asd
match    | (OOC)
match    | -OOC- 
match2x  | asd OOC asd OOC asd
```

:$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
[^a-zA-Z\d](OOC)[^a-zA-Z\d]
```

- `^` - Negates everything inside square brackets, so it matches non numeric characters and non letters.
- `a-zA-Z` - Matches all the letters.
- `\d` - Numeric class.